# How to set the PhantomJSOptions in Selenium for proxy-type?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

Using Selenium and the web driver to drive phantomjs as part of a web scraping project. From the "Known Issues" for Windows at PhantomJS, it is suggested that the proxy-type be set to "none" to speed up network performance.

I tried the following:

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("proxy", "{proxyType:none}");
```

However, this sets proxy to a string and I think I need a json object. Can someone show me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the driver service to set options:

```
var phantomJSDriverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(phantomJsDir);
phantomJSDriverService.ProxyType = "none";
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(phantomJSDriverService);
```

Comment: The docs didn't show ProxyType as a property. Thanks for the info. Now if only you had some ideas on how to make it more stable! Crashes after a handful of GoToUrl(page)'s.

Comment: I can now answer the crashes question... upgrade to phantomjs.exe 1.9.1 and all is great. No crashes after 30 minutes of running so far.